# Visualforce page for new Lookup Page

Tags: apex, lookup

I have followed the instructions of this blog post (http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/) to try and create 2 separate vf pages in order to override the standard lookup page that is on the opportunity field. Both of my visualforce pages and controllers work but I have two problems: 1) Where do I find the custom lookup that I created (it is not on the opportunity page where I wanted it to be) 2) How do I get the two visualforce pages to integrate with each other? I have put the url in the first vf page where I needed to change the url to match my vf pages name. Can anyone help  me out with this?

MyCustomLookupController

```
public with sharing class MyCustomLookupController {

   public Opportunity opportunity {get;set;}

public MyCustomLookupController() {
opportunity = new Opportunity();
}

}
```

VF Page for Lookup Page:

```
<apex:page controller="MyCustomLookupController" id="Page" tabstyle="Opportunity">

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function openLookup(baseURL, width, modified, searchParam){
var originalbaseURL = baseURL;
var originalwidth = width;
var originalmodified = modified;
var originalsearchParam = searchParam;

var lookupType = baseURL.substr(baseURL.length-3, 3);
if (modified == '1') baseURL = baseURL + searchParam;

var isCustomLookup = false;

 // Following "001" is the lookup type for Account Department object so change this as per your standard or custom object
if(lookupType == "a1D"){

  var urlArr = baseURL.split("&");
  var txtId = '';
  if(urlArr.length > 2) {
    urlArr = urlArr[1].split('=');
    txtId = urlArr[1];
  }

  // Following is the url of Custom Lookup page. You need to change that accordingly
  baseURL = "/apex/AccDepLookUpPage2?txt=" + txtId;

  // Following is the id of apex:form control "myForm". You need to change that accordingly
  baseURL = baseURL + "&frm=" + escapeUTF("{!$Component.myForm}");
  if (modified == '1') {
    baseURL = baseURL + "&lksearch=" + searchParam;
  }

  // Following is the ID of inputField that is the lookup to be customized as custom lookup
  if(txtId.indexOf('Department__c') > -1 ){
    isCustomLookup = true;
  }
}


if(isCustomLookup == true){
  openPopup(baseURL, "lookup", 350, 480, "width="+width+",height=480,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollable=no", true);
}
  else {
     if (modified == '1') originalbaseURL = originalbaseURL + originalsearchParam;
  openPopup(originalbaseURL, "lookup", 350, 480, "width="+originalwidth+",height=480,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollable=no", true);
     } 
  }
</script>

<apex:sectionHeader title="Account Department"  subtitle="Custom Lookup" />

    <apex:form id="myForm">  
            <apex:PageBlock id="PageBlock">                
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Custom Lookup">
    <apex:inputField id="Department__c" value="{!opportunity.Account_Department__c}"  />
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:PageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

CustomAccountDepartmentLookupController

```
   public with sharing class CustomAccountDepartmentLookupController {

     public Department__c acctdep {get;set;} // new account department to create
   public List<Department__c> results{get;set;} // search results
   public string searchString{get;set;} // search keyword

   public CustomAccountDepartmentLookupController() {
       acctdep = new Department__c();
       // get the current search string
      searchString = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('lksrch');
      runSearch();  
   }

  // performs the keyword search
  public PageReference search() {
   runSearch();
   return null;
  }

  // prepare the query and issue the search command
  private void runSearch() {
         // TODO prepare query string for complex serarches & prevent injections
    results = performSearch(searchString);               
  } 

  // run the search and return the records found. 
 private List<Department__c> performSearch(string searchString) {

String soql = 'select id, name from Department__c';
if(searchString != '' && searchString != null)
  soql = soql +  ' where name LIKE \'%' + searchString +'%\'';
soql = soql + ' limit 10';
System.debug(soql);
return database.query(soql); 

 }

// save the new account department record
public PageReference saveAccountDepartment() {
  insert acctdep;
  // reset the account
  acctdep = new Department__c();
  return null;
}

// used by the visualforce page to send the link to the right dom element
public string getFormTag() {
  return System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('frm');
}

// used by the visualforce page to send the link to the right dom element for the text   box
public string getTextBox() {
  return System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('txt');
}

}
```

Second VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="CustomAccountDepartmentLookupController"
  title="Search" 
  showHeader="false" 
  sideBar="false" 
  tabStyle="Department__c" 
  id="pg">

  <apex:form >
  <apex:outputPanel id="page" layout="block" style="margin:5px;padding:10px;padding-top:2px;">
                <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name1" id="tabbedPanel">

                  <!-- SEARCH TAB -->
      <apex:tab label="Search" name="tab1" id="tabOne">

                    <apex:actionRegion >  
                                  <apex:outputPanel id="top" layout="block" style="margin:5px;padding:10px;padding-top:2px;">
                                    <apex:outputLabel value="Search" style="font-weight:Bold;padding-right:10px;" for="txtSearch"/>
                                    <apex:inputText id="txtSearch" value="{!searchString}" />
                                      <span style="padding-left:5px"><apex:commandButton id="btnGo" value="Go" action="{!Search}" rerender="searchResults"></apex:commandButton></span>
                                  </apex:outputPanel>

                            <apex:outputPanel id="pnlSearchResults" style="margin:10px;height:350px;overflow-Y:auto;" layout="block">
                                    <apex:pageBlock id="searchResults"> 
                                      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!results}" var="a" id="tblResults">
                                        <apex:column >
                                          <apex:facet name="header">
                                            <apex:outputPanel >Name</apex:outputPanel>
                                          </apex:facet>
                                           <apex:outputLink value="javascript:top.window.opener.lookupPick2('{!FormTag}','{!TextBox}_lkid','{!TextBox}','{!a.Id}','{!a.Name}', false)" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(a.Id))}">{!a.Name}</apex:outputLink>     
                                        </apex:column>
                                      </apex:pageBlockTable>
                                    </apex:pageBlock>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:actionRegion>

                  </apex:tab>

                  <!-- NEW ACCOUNT TAB -->
                  <apex:tab label="New Account Department" name="tab2" id="tabTwo">

        <apex:pageBlock id="newDepartment__c" title="New Account Department" >

          <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!saveAccountDepartment}" value="Save"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
          <apex:pageMessages />

          <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
            <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Department__c.FieldSets.CustomAccountDepartmentLookup}" var="f">
              <apex:inputField value="{!acctdep[f]}"/>
            </apex:repeat>
          </apex:pageBlockSection> 
        </apex:pageBlock>

                  </apex:tab>
                </apex:tabPanel>
  </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: For some reason it is not showing the whole vf page on the second one. Let me know if you want me to paste the parts it left out if they are important.

Comment: I think I got all of your code in the code formatted blocks.  Your code has to all be indented at least 4 spaces from the left margin.  Or, you can just click the '{}' button on the editing toolbar to automatically format selected text (good for when you paste code in).  There's a little orange (?) icon on the top right of the editing toolbar, too, that has some more on formatting help.

Comment: Thanks Peter! Do you by chance know the answer to my question?

Answer (score 1):

1) Where do I find the custom lookup that I created (it is not on the opportunity page where I wanted it to be)

If you read the article jeff says

*I have some good news and some bad news. For standard page layouts I can’t help you. Go vote for this idea and this idea. However, for Visualforce page I have a solution to all of these problems with code!*

If you want to modify the lookup on a standard pagelayout its not going to happen. Alternatively you can add the VF page as a section on the oppty page layout (Crappy but thats the option we have)

[image]

2) How do I get the two visualforce pages to integrate with each other? I have put the url in the first vf page where I needed to change the url to match my vf pages name

When you click the lookup icon on the first vf page the second vf page loads up. If you had followed the tutorial blind then there is a good chance that you have already set up the second vf page. Please clarify if this is not the case and if you are struck with the second one still

Please explain what the use case is so that someone here can help.The tutorial shows how to create a custom lookup on a VF page and this cannot be applied on a standard lookup field. There is no way to override the lookup fields.

**UPDATE:**
You are on the right track layout section--> visualforce pages area is where you got to look.

In order for you to get the VF page as part of the opportunity page layout you need to modify your code as below:

```
 <apex:page standardcontroller="Opportunity" extensions="MyCustomLookupController" id="Page" tabstyle="Opportunity">
```

the standardcontroller="opportunity" ties the page to the object giving access to VF page area on the oppty pagelayout.

*Also, I have both pages set up, it is just that when you click on the lookup icon from the first page, it doesn't bring up the second vf page.*

I am suspecting the culprit could be pop up blocker. Try to see if you have disabled pop ups for salesforce.com

Comment: In trying to add the vf page to my opportunity layout it doesn't appear in the edit layout section--> visualforce pages area. Also, I have both pages set up, it is just that when you click on the lookup icon from the first page, it doesn't bring up the second vf page.

Comment: please see update

Comment: I did change the controller to Opportunity and that worked, do you think that would be the same issue for the second vf page? The pop up blocker isn't the issue since a window pops open it is just the standard window that keeps opening and not the vf page that I want it to connect with

Comment: what happens when you click the lookup? does it open up another page and says "VF error. page does not exist" or some kind of error message?

Comment: No it opens up the standard search results page that the regular field lookup window already brings up (Recently viewed results)

Comment: Can you screenshot what you see when you click the lookup icon in your original question.

Comment: I guess I don't know how to add the print screen shot into here. It won't let me paste

Comment: you got to save the image to ur desktop and add the image to the question, you cannot copy paste the image you can only upload it

Comment: It is on there now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12607/discussion-between-rao-and-newbiedeveloper27)

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with @rao...they came up with this solution:

/_ui/common/data/LookupPage?lkfm=Page%3AmyForm&lknm=Page%3AmyForm%3APageBlock%3A‌​j_id2%3AAccount&lktp=BUSINESS_HOURS_LOOKUP

ok now replace the if(lookupType == "a1D"){
with %5D

i mean
if(lookupType == "%5D"){

you should see the custom page :)

Comment: Now the two pages interact with one another, however I can't get the field to appear on the Opportunity Edit layout since it is a visualforce page. Does anyone have a workaround so that the field would appear as a text field on the Opportunity layout and the custom lookup window would appear?